# GLFW functions not found

Tags: c++, cmake, ubuntu-16.04, glfw

I try to compile a program that uses GLFW3 library on Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64. I installed `libglfw3` and `libglfw3-dev` packages. Next, I wrote `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (Test)
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-lGL -lGLEW")
set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS -lglfw )
add_executable(Test src/main.cpp)
```

And **main.cpp**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main() {

    if (!glfwInit()) {
        return -1;
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

But I get an error from `make` command:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `glfwInit'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/Test.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'Test' failed
make[2]: *** [Test] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Test.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Test.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What do I doing wrong? Why can it not find GLFW3?

Comment: Did you link to the GLEW library?

Comment: I thought this string `set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS -lglfw )` must link this library, it isn't? Just I only learn CMake. I used Visual Studio project system and its compiler on Windows.

Comment: You compiled the GLFW library on Ubuntu but you're trying to run the program in Windows Visual Studio?

Comment: No-no, I said that I never wrote C++ program on Linux early using CMake for makelist generation. So, I learn it now and thought that so stirng I can link this library.

Comment: How can I link it? I tried clone this library from repository and compiled. And link it like a static library but it gave all same error too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131452/discussion-between-titone-maurice-and-).

Comment: You say you use GLFW but try to link with GLEW. If you're actually trying to use glew, then you should check out [FindGLEW](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/FindGLEW.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native way for link with library in CMake is [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/target_link_libraries.html):

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (Test)
add_executable(Test src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Test GL GLEW glfw)
```

Note, that this works only if GL and other libs are installed to the default places, known to compiler and linker. Otherwise it is better to use [find_package(GLEW)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/FindGLEW.html) and other `find_package()` calls, as noted by @tambre.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this solution.